# Laravel vue with html2canvas error in cors when trying to convert the html to image

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vuejs2, html2canvas

Have tried crossorigin="" or anonymous but wont work. Some of my friend able to download it with no issue using the google storage image link.

Is there other libray to use instead of html2canvas that will bypass the cors since the image is already showing in src attribute but the html2canvas is having error when downloading?

Im expecting to convert the html to image but it download without image since the src with image link is having error.

method code in vue with html2canvas

```
    convertToImage() {
      const element = document.getElementById('image-id');


  html2canvas(element, { 
    allowTaint: true,
    useCORS: true,
   }).then((canvas) => {
    const image = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = image;
    link.download = 'generatedImage.png';
    link.click();
  });
  },
```

Code in laravel in middleware for header

```
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', ['*'])
        ->header('X-Frame-Options', 'DENY')
        ->header('X-XSS-Protection', '1; mode=block')
        ->header('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff')
        ->header('Strict-Transport-Security', 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding');
        

    }
```

Error:

```
Access to image at 'https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo11w.png' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: what request is being blocked? there's no request (to the server) I can see

Comment: @JaromandaX the image link that has cors since this link is from Google storage. The html2canvas will request again to link of `src` when it try to convert it to image.

Comment: @JaromandaX try this `https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo11w.png` wont work to

Comment: where does that appear in the code? but yes, you can't use that image in a canvas - not sure how that laravel code is at all relevant, surely you don't own `www.google.de` do you?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, i dont own the sample link. Header set up laravel was unnecessary i think, just trying my luck

Comment: since the request isn't being made via your server, then your server is not how to fix this ... except that it is ... you can use your server to proxy your request to google

Comment: @JaromandaX  { 
    allowTaint: true,
    useCORS: true,
    proxy: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`,
   }

Have tried this, still same